# How to show that $\Re(\frac{e^{i \theta}+z}{e^{i \theta}-z})=\frac{1+|z|^2}{|z-e^{i \theta}|^2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to show that $\Re(\frac{e^{i \theta}+z}{e^{i \theta}-z})=\frac{1+|z|^2}{|z-e^{i \theta}|^2}$?

I have got $\Re(\frac{e^{i \theta}+z}{e^{i \theta}-z})=\frac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}$. Is this right?

Comment: Does $|w+z|=|w|+|z|$ hold? Try $z = -w$.

Comment: Both statements are wrong. Try $\theta = 0$, $z = -1$ to see this. It should be $1-|z|^2$ in the numerator. Show us your work so that we can tell you what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\Re z= \frac{1}{2}(z+z^*)$.